# Target CPU temperature for AMD FX processor

Tags: fan, cooling, temperature

I have got an [AsRock 980DE3/U3S3 R2.0](http://www.asrock.com/MB/AMD/980DE3U3S3%20R2.0/index.asp) motherboard with the FX-6300 procesor. I am using the stock cooler. What is the recommended target temperature to set in the fan speed control in BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

For FX-6300 CPU in general 62C is the maximum safe temperature. Anything below that is fine. If your CPU gets hotter than that without you overclocking it then you should invest in a better cooler and thermal paste.

Comment: The CPU steadies on about 63 to 65 °C according to HWmonitor in a hot room when stress testing. Is this safe?

Comment: In reality actual safe temperature is probably somewhere in 70's, but companies love to lower those numbers so you dont claim warranty if something does die. Given that you will probably never run your CPU at 100% for over 5 minutes, your setup should be good enough.